# batch delete records in database table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete multiple records at once.

I have two tables, one that contains

```
comments: comment_id, comment, author_id
news_comments: news_id, comment_id
```

I want to delete all records from the news_comments where author_id = 1 in the comments table.

I tried doing this, but it gave me an error about the sub query returning more than one item:

```
delete from news_items where comment_id = 
(select comment_id from comments where author_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete from news_items where comment_id IN 
(select comment_id from comments where author_id = 1)
                                        ^^
                                        IN
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
delete from news_items where comment_id in 
(select comment_id from comments where author_id = 1)
```